# changing Specific section background image in wordpress

Tags: theme-development

How do I change specific section background image in wordpress?

I have a background image set via CSS:

```
.section3 {
    background: url(bg.jpg) no repeat;
}
```

Say I want to change this image later via the WordPress dashboard. How would I do this? I want to add functionality so that user can change the image in future.

The default background function only enables the user to change the background color on the page. I want to target this specific section.

Comment: Do you want to make the css change to be persistent across theme changes or last only for a single change? Also, is the section a main site area like 'blog' or is it more of an individual post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Customizer API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) ( [Advanced Topics](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/) ) to a modify a dynamic background.

---

**UPDATE**

[Eric Lewis](https://gist.github.com/ericandrewlewis) just presented an [idea last night](http://slides.com/ericlewis-1/customize-anything#/) that might make it possible to customize single post content, not just global theme options using Customizer. Check out [Custom CSS per post in WordPress](https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/wp-custom-css-per-post). He also shows how to add a button to the edit post page which brings up the the customizer in a modal window for faster AJAX previews.

---

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/ericandrewlewis/2310fd6d7dabf0696965)

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function($hook_suffix) {
    if ( in_array( $hook_suffix, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'customize-loader' );
    }
} );

add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', function() {
    $customize_url = add_query_arg(

        array(
            // current page
            'url' => urlencode( get_post_permalink() ),

            // custom url
            // 'url' => urlencode( home_url() . '/page-to-preview/' ),

            // deeplink to panel
            // 'autofocus' => array( 'panel' => 'widgets' )
        ),

        wp_customize_url()
    );

    ?><button class="load-customize"
              href="<?php echo esc_url( $customize_url ) ?>"
              type="button">Show In Customizer</button>
    <?php
} );
```

---

[image]

There are also [contextual controls](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#contextual-controls-sections-and-panels) if you want to target specific pages.

[image]

[image]
[image]

But I think the easiest way to use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/).

Answer (score 1):

Using the customizer, add this piece of code in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'customize_register' , 'my_theme_options' );
function my_theme_options( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('mytheme_section_bg_img', array(
            'title'       => __( 'Section name', 'my_theme_slug' ),
            'priority'    => 100,
            'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
            'description' => __('Select a background image', 'my_theme_slug'), 
        ) 
    );  

    $wp_customize->add_setting('section_bg_img');

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'section_bg_img', array(
            'label'    => __( 'Background image', 'my_theme_slug' ), 
            'section'  => 'mytheme_section_bg_img',
            'settings' => 'section_bg_img',
            'priority' => 10,
        ) 
    ));
}
```

You must change "my_theme_slug" by your theme slug.

Once done, you must select an image from the customizer, and finally print it wherever you want using this code:

```
<div<?php

    if ( $section_bg_img = get_theme_mod( 'section_bg_img' ) )
        echo ' style="background-image: url(' . $section_bg_img . ');"';

?>></div>
```

Hope it helps!