# Section Background Images?

Tags: themes, custom-background

First time poster here... I'm creating a new site on the hosted Wordpress site with a friend. It's going to have each blog post divided into 4 'sections' (we're titling them: bramble, thorns, paths, fruit). We would like to have a background image for each section (separated by an image and heading title).

So my question is two fold - first, are there some themes out there that support this? Or is this something I can do in the admin console? (If so I don't think I have seen it, so if someone can point me to it, let me know.) And bonus points if the theme has a sitemap and sliding side menu.

For reference, I looked at this post, but this seemed more about developing/desigining a theme.
[changing Specific section background image in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210330/changing-specific-section-background-image-in-wordpress)

I am more interested in selecting and configuring a theme to do this. I'm not interested in doing development.

Thanks in advance!
Paul

Comment: Learning the Customizer to style posts and pages  is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your theme pages to support this change. If you already have a background in place you can modify it on a per post basis using the technics describe in that post.

This plugin [Custom CSS per post in WordPress](https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/wp-custom-css-per-post) is a good example at setting custom css per page.

The **pro** to this is you can copy/paste your desired CSS markup to all the pages you want to adjust. Assuming a background image is in place then level of effort on your end is minimal.

The **con** is that keeping up with changes means adjusting CSS on individual pages in the future.

---

Another method is creating a custom metabox that give you a selector of the type of section you want.

```
<?php

// Register your Meta Box

function add_theme_section_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
            'theme_section_meta_box',          // $id
            'Theme Section',                   // $title
            'show_theme_section_meta_box',     // $callback
            'post',                            // $page
            'normal',                          // $context
            'high' );
}

add_action( "add_meta_boxes", "add_theme_section_meta_box" );

// Render the meta box on the edit page

function show_theme_section_meta_box( $post ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'theme_section', true );
    if ( ! $meta || $meta === 0 ) {
        $meta = false;
    }
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), "theme-section-meta-box-nonce" );
    $sections = array (
            0         => 'None',
            'bramble' => 'Bramble',
            'thorns'  => 'Thorns',
            'paths'   => 'Paths',
            'fruit'   => 'Fruit',
    );
    ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="theme_section">Section</label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="theme_section" id="theme_section">
                    <?php foreach ( $sections as $section => $sectionTitle ) {
                        $selected = $meta === $section;
                        printf( "<option %s value='%s'>%s</option>", $selected ? 'selected' : '', $section, $sectionTitle );
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

// Save the meta when saving a post

function save_theme_section( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ "theme-section-meta-box-nonce" ] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ "theme-section-meta-box-nonce" ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( "edit_post", $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if ( defined( "DOING_AUTOSAVE" ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $slug = "post";
    if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $theme_section = '';
    if ( isset( $_POST[ "theme_section" ] ) ) {
        $theme_section = $_POST[ "theme_section" ];
    }
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "theme_section", $theme_section );
}

add_action( "save_post", "save_theme_section", 10, 3 );
```

Then when you want to display a background, you would simply need to check if the page you're looking at has that setting and decide what to do about it.

```
$theme_section = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'theme_section', true );

if ( $theme_section && $theme_section !== 0 ) {

    switch ($theme_section){

        case 'bramble':
            // ...
            break;
        case 'thorns':
            // ...
            break;
        case 'paths':
            // ...
            break;
        case 'fruit':
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

---

A third method is to use [Term Meta](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/) which is like custom fields for [categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/). Then you could specify details for your custom taxonomy there -- like the image to use.

Looks like there might be a plugin for it - [WP Term Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-images/)